# problem with primerfaces gmap tag

Tags: primefaces

I tried to use a simple gmap example to start to developt a webapp, but it doesn´t work for me.

I used the **example prime movie-collector**  that I found on the web page. I only included this code `<p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" style="width:600px;height:400px" />`  in template.html file.

I got this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /template.xhtml @39,39 <p:gmap> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui, but no tag was defined for name: gmap
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
```

I think that I haven´t wrong libraries.

Another day, I tried to create my own example using a simple map, but I obtained the same output.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest PrimeFaces jar. http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html

The following must be in the head section:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

`<p:gmap>` must be inside `<f:view contentType="text/html"></f:view>` for it to render in Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!

I´m using PRIMEFACES 2.0.1. 

I made sure that I put gmap tag inside a <f:view> tag, as you said and I included the script.

I continue with the some error, any more idea?

Comment: Yeah use version 2.2.RC2 there was a bug fixed in version 2.1 that sounds like the issue your having: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1003